# GWT back button browser

Tags: gwt, browser-history

For example current page is www.google.com.
But I typed a different website address in address bar and clicked. This site has fully
GWT code.

But I like to back to the previous page of www.google.com.
So I clicked back button of browser.but how can I get event of back button from current
GWT code. Can I set any backbutton event handler in GWT of current page?
One which notifies an alert to me that back button was pressed.

Is there any solution from GWT?

Answer (score 6):

+1 to Igor and Alex. Here's some code you can use, if you want to use the ClosingHandler:

```
    Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onWindowClosing(final ClosingEvent event) {
            event.setMessage("Don't you think my site is awesome?");
        }
    });
```

Some info from the Javadoc of ClosingHandler.onWindowClosing():

```
 /* Fired just before the browser window closes or navigates to a different
  * site. No user-interface may be displayed during shutdown. */
```

Answer (score 5):

There's [`Window.ClosingEvent`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.ClosingEvent.html):

> Fired just before the browser window
>   closes or navigates to a different
>   site.

The other option is [`History.addValueChangeHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#addValueChangeHandler(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeHandler)), which listens for changes in the browser's history stack (see [the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) for more info).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [`HistoryListener`](http://www.ing.iac.es/gwt-linux-1.4.60/doc/javadoc/com/google/gwt/user/client/HistoryListener.html) interface: your class's method `onHistoryChanged` will be called (with a `String` token) on every click to the back and forward buttons. You can then interact with the [History](http://www.ing.iac.es/gwt-linux-1.4.60/doc/javadoc/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html) class, which has e.g. a `back()` static method to "go back".  However, I'm not entirely sure if it goes back all the way to *before* GWT started (but it's sure worth trying;-).

Comment: `HistoryListener` and in general *Listeners are deprecated as of GWT 1.6 - you should use the appropriate Handlers instead (in this case it's a `ValueChangeHandler`, which might not be as obvious as say `HistoryHandler`).

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewNativeEvent(final NativePreviewEvent event) {
            if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYDOWN) {
                if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE) {
                    Element element = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());

                    String tagName = element.getTagName();

                    System.out.println(tagName);

                    // Add checks for other input controls
                    if (!tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("INPUT") 
                                 && !tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("TEXTAREA")) {

                        boolean result = Window.confirm("Are you sure?");
                        if (!result) {
                            event.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this native code

```
 public native void call()/*-{

    $wnd.onkeydown = GetChar;

     function GetChar (event)
     {
        var key = event.keyCode;

        var bb = event.target.nodeName;

        if(key==8 && bb=="BODY")//checking keyCode of key for backspace
                {
                    var x= window.confirm("Are you sureyou want to leave the page");

                    if (x==true)
                            {
                                window.history.back();
                            }
                    else if(x==false)
                            {

                                return false;
                            }
                }
        }                   
}-*/;
```

Comment: these all are working on back space press by user . is there any method to prompt user on browser back button..?